# Not able to connect to remote computer with ip address

Tags: tomcat, networking, service, tcp, ports

I want to run a url of different machine like

```
http://192.168.7.1:8080
```

But it gets timed out.

On this machine(having ipaddress - 192.168.7.1) if I run the same url, it works.

Does anybody knows any setting which is off on machine 192.168.7.1 to allow remote connection? Please help.

Comment: First thing to do is to check firewall.

Comment: Thanks for reply ... But I don't have much knowledge of networking. Can you please tell me where can I allow TCP connection to 8080

Comment: Is this a Windows or Unix machine?

Comment: Go to Start menu.  Type "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" which will bring up a window.  Go to Inbound rules.  Add a new Inbound rule to allow connections on port 8080.

Comment: thanks it worked .. it was same firewall issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall

As somebody before me said, it's quite likely it's firewall related.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's firewall related. You should add a rule which allows TCP connections to port 8080 on your machine having the ip 192.168.7.1.

Comment: Thanks for reply ... But I don't have much knowledge of networking. Can you please tell me where can I allow TCP connection to 8080

Comment: Depends on your Operation System.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the fact that 192.168.7.1 address is private one. If your second machine is in different subnet you will not be able to reach it using private address (rather public address of your gateway).

If the machines are in the same network (both has the same network addresses - 192.168.7.X; assuming that netmask is 24 bits) please check if you can e.g. ping one host from other.

So in nutshell:
If the address of your second host is 192.168.7.X this is most probably network issue (FW, routing, ...) if not you will not be able to reach second machine using its local address (of course some advanced networks could use some advanced routing but let's focus on general stuff...)